# how to pass a <![CDATA[(...)]]> String to a XML file?

Tags: java, html, xml, cdata

I need to pass a `<![cdata[something-html-formatted]]>` to a xml file where I parse it as a html email body. All is working except retrieving correctly the email body.
Say, for instance, I have a string like this:

`<![CDATA[I need to write <b>this</b> text in <i>italic</i>]]>`

I always get the result on the email like this:

this</b> text in italic</i>]]>

How can I pass the complete string to the XML file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you generating the cdata in the xml file?  also note that as a general rule, whatever your problem is, cdata is not the solution.

Comment: What are you using to send the email. Check format of your email. Is it marked as "HTML" format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply encode it, like you would everything else, by replacing `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`:

```
<xml>
&lt;![CDATA[I need to write &lt;b&gt;this&lt;/b&gt; text in 
&lt;i&gt;italic&lt;/i&gt;]]&gt;
</xml>
```

works fine.

Comment: The only situation where `>` needs to be escaped is the closing of a CDATA tag when serializing XML.  You found an edge case.  Its safe to always escape/unescape `>` though some frameworks do not do this for you.